# List two records per column in Rails loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to loop through two records per matchId but getting an error.

```
undefined method `first' for 1:Fixnum
```

Hoping to list the data in a table view with team 1, team 2 and goals all in the same row. Is there a better method to achieve this result? Or am I on the right track, but missing something?

**Database**

```
|matchId|      matchDate    |teamId|goals|
|  101  |2016-05-14 11:40:00|  10  |  3  |
|  101  |2016-05-14 11:40:00|  20  |  2  |
|  102  |2016-05-14 13:30:00|  11  |  0  |
|  102  |2016-05-14 13:30:00|  21  |  1  |
```

**Controller**

```
@match = Match.all.group_by { |m| m.matchDate.beginning_of_week }
```

**View**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <% @match.each do |date, games| %>
    <tr class="match-date">
      <td colspan='5'><%= date.strftime('%d %B, %Y') %></td>
    </tr>
      <% games.group_by(&:matchId).each do |m, t| %>
        <% t.each do |d| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= d.teamId.first  %></td>
            <td><%= d.goals.first %></td>
            <td>Defeated</td>
            <td><%= d.teamId.last  %></td>
            <td><%= d.goals.last %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second loop is not needed because you are trying to access both. Then you are accessing the attributes and calling first on the attribute not on a collection of matches. You should try something like this.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <% @match.each do |date, games| %>
    <tr class="match-date">
      <td colspan='5'><%= date.strftime('%d %B, %Y') %></td>
    </tr>
      <% games.group_by(&:matchId).each do |m, t| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= t.first.teamId %></td>
            <td><%= t.first.goals %></td>
            <td>Defeated</td>
            <td><%= t.last.teamId  %></td>
            <td><%= t.last.goals %></td>
          </tr>
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank yo us much. Nailed it!

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking since your records are ordered , you should be able to use [each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) and get 2 records each time. That will eliminate your second lool

High level code would be

```
@match.each_slice(2) do |element|
  <tr>
    <td><% = element.first %></td>
    <td><% = element.last %></td> 
  <tr>
end
```